# python 3.9.1 datetime arithmetic

Tags: datetime, python-3.9

While trying the new zoneinfo support in python3.9.1, I noticed that time differences of datetime aware objects differ from those produced by pytz as shown by the output of the below program:

```
import datetime,zoneinfo,pytz
from sys import version_info
print(f'Python{version_info.major}.{version_info.minor}{version_info.micro}'
f' pytz{pytz.__version__}')
Athens=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('Europe/Athens')
f='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d=[datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-10-25 00:00:00',f),
   datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-10-25 23:59:59',f)]
print('naive   ',d[1]-d[0])
d=[x.astimezone(Athens) for x in d]
print('zoneinfo',d[1]-d[0])
d=[datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-10-25 00:00:00',f),
   datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-10-25 23:59:59',f)]
athens=pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens')
print('pytz as ',d[1].astimezone(athens)-d[0].astimezone(athens))
print('pytz loc',athens.localize(d[1])-athens.localize(d[0]))

Python3.91 pytz2020.4
naive    23:59:59
zoneinfo 23:59:59
pytz as  1 day, 0:59:59
pytz loc 1 day, 0:59:59
```

It appears that the native timezone supports ignores the  fact that 2020-10-25 was the day of changeover from summertime to winter time and therefore that day's duration was 25 hours.
What am I missing?

Comment: after closer inspection, I think [this](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html) is what you're missing. The timedelta you get from aware datetime with a zoneinfo tzinfo is "DST aware"; it shows wall time. That's the same for dateutil btw. With pytz's timezones, this doesn't seem to be the case. It's a pain ^^

Comment: related: [Python 3.9: Construct DST valid timestamp using standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64440016/10197418)

Comment: @MrFuppes, thank you. I need to think about it.

Comment: I hope this helps. Also note [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64452687/10197418) to the linked question and the discussion I had with him in the comments. I still find this whole "wall time timedelta" thing hard to grasp. I like to think of time in a physical sense but maybe that's too naive in the real world ^^

Comment: @MrFuppes, his case is well presented but not convincing. Counter-intuitive is sometimes just an euphemism for wrong. Documenting a bug does not make it a feature.

Comment: Not sure how well this is even documented, at least to me, it's not obvious in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). Furthermore, Python packages do it differently than the standard lib as you have noted. Another example, `pandas` treats naive datetime as UTC whilst Python's datetime assumes local time. Can be confusing... I guess some things could have been done differently from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An illustration of my comment; aware datetime with `tzinfo` set with a ZoneInfo from `zoneinfo` returns a wall time timedelta. If you do the same with `pytz.timezone` aware datetime, you get absolute time timedelta.

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
import pytz
from sys import version_info

print(f'Python {version_info.major}.{version_info.minor}{version_info.micro} pytz {pytz.__version__}')
# Python 3.90 pytz 2020.4

d=[datetime.fromisoformat('2020-10-25 00:00:00'), datetime.fromisoformat('2020-10-25 23:59:59')]

Athens = ZoneInfo('Europe/Athens')
print('wall time diff, zoneinfo:', d[1].replace(tzinfo=Athens)-d[0].replace(tzinfo=Athens))
# wall time diff, zoneinfo: 23:59:59

athens = pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens')
print('absolute time diff, pytz:', athens.localize(d[1])-athens.localize(d[0]))
# absolute time diff, pytz: 1 day, 0:59:59

# to get absolute time delta with zoneinfo:
utc = ZoneInfo('UTC')
print('absolute time diff, zoneinfo:', d[1].replace(tzinfo=Athens).astimezone(utc)
                                      -d[0].replace(tzinfo=Athens).astimezone(utc))
# absolute time diff, zoneinfo: 1 day, 0:59:59
```