# Python datetime: unexpected dependency between timedelta and daylight saving time

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta, dst

I want to know if there's a daylight saving time change within the next hours. Thereby I recognized an unexpected dependency between datetime.timedelta, astimezone and daylight saving time. During the daylight saving time change the timedelta calculation seems no to work. Here's a simple example:

```
import datetime
import pytz

format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
local_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
time_diff = datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)

print((datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 26, 1, 0, 0) + time_diff).astimezone(local_tz).strftime(format))
# => 2023-02-26 02:00:00 CET+0100

print((datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 26, 1, 0, 0) + time_diff).astimezone(local_tz).strftime(format))
# => 2023-03-26 01:00:00 CET+0100
```

I would expect that the last print would result "2023-03-26 02:00:00 CET+0100" or "2023-03-26 03:00:00 CEST+0200". Does anyone can explain this behaviour?

After different tries I found a solution by adding the time delta after adding the timezone to the timestamp.

```
print((datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 26, 1, 0, 0).astimezone(local_tz) + time_diff).strftime(format))
```

But I still don't understand the error in my first used code.

My versions:
- Python 3.10.2
- pytz 2022.7

Comment: maybe this helps: [Adding timedelta to local datetime, unexpected behaviour accross DST shift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72804395/10197418). What's really weird here is that the addition of a timedelta results in a non-existent time; there should be no 2 am on that date, only 3 am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64452687/10197418) by Paul Ganssle - with native Python's timedelta combined with time zones, non-existing datetimes (like 2023-02-26 02:00:00 CET+0100) have to be expected.

Here's a slightly extended comparison for reference, + comments in the code. pytz is deprecated since the release of Python 3.9's zoneinfo.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
import pandas as pd
import pytz

def absolute_add(dt: datetime, td: timedelta) -> datetime:
    utc_in = dt.astimezone(timezone.utc)  # Convert input to UTC
    utc_out = utc_in + td  # Do addition in UTC
    civil_out = utc_out.astimezone(dt.tzinfo)  # Back to original tzinfo
    return civil_out

# -----
# in vanilla Python, we can create non-existent datetime...

# I) tz already set
t = datetime(2023, 3, 26, 1, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin"))
print(t + timedelta(hours=1))
# 2023-03-26 02:00:00+01:00
# this datetime should not exist in that time zone since there is a DST transtion,
# 1 am UTC+1 plus one hour gives 3 am UTC+2

# II) tz set after timedelta addition
print(datetime(2023, 3, 26, 1) + timedelta(hours=1))
# 2023-03-26 02:00:00
# this is ok since no tz specified
print((datetime(2023, 3, 26, 1) + timedelta(hours=1)).replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin")))
# 2023-03-26 02:00:00+01:00
# again, we have a non-existent datetime
print((datetime(2023, 3, 26, 1) + timedelta(hours=1)).astimezone(ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin")))
# 2023-03-26 01:00:00+01:00
# also a bit confusing; 2 am would be non-existing, so the hour is "corrected"
# backwards before setting the time zone
```

```py
# -----
# adding the timedelta in UTC as "absolute duration" works as expected:
print(absolute_add(t, timedelta(hours=1)))
# 2023-03-26 03:00:00+02:00

# with pytz timezones, you can normalize to correct the non-existent datetime:
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")
t = tz.localize(datetime(2023, 3, 26, 1))
print(tz.normalize(t + timedelta(hours=1)))
# 2023-03-26 03:00:00+02:00

# this is correctly implemented in pandas for instance:
t = pd.Timestamp(2023, 3, 26, 1).tz_localize("Europe/Berlin")
print(t + pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
# 2023-03-26 03:00:00+02:00
```